# Want to test migrated wordpress website on new server, but it redirects to old URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

```
Hi Team,

I have a wordpress website, which I have migrated to a new Amazon AWS EC2 Linux Free Tier Instance.

The steps I followed are:
1. Backed up wordpress files(public_html folder) and database.
2. Installed LAMP, SSL and PhpMyAdmin on new server(followed Amazon Tutorials).
3. Copied wordpress files backup to new server under /var/www/html folder.
4. Created required database and required user on new server.
5. Edited wp-config.php with required details: dbname, dbuser, dbpassword, ...
6. Imported the backedup database file on new server.
7. Tried accessing the new url which installed wordpress.

Everything upto here worked fine.

But now, when I access wp-admin console or home page url, it redirects to the old server and instead of displaying the EC2 public DNS name in the browser address bar, the old url is displayed which I do not want (I understand I have not changed the domain mapping to the new server ip address yet.)

Because unless and until I am sure, that the site functions well on new server, I do not want to map the domain name to the new server ip address.

I want to test my site functioning on the new server without mapping the domain name to the new server ip and I want the EC2 instance public DNS to be displayed in the browser's address bar.

I have tried several ways for doing this: 
- Edited /etc/hosts with ip and EC2 public DNS name.
- Replaced old url with new url in database backup file using notepad++ as 
  well as the script on github.
- Changed the old url in .htaccess as well.
- Added certain constants in wp-config.php.
- Manually changed the url entries in database for certain tables like 
  cp_options, cp_posts, cp_postmeta

But all lead to server disconnection, phpmyadmin hangs and wp-admin also doesnt open up.

I need to stop and start the new server to access all these again.

Request you to please help me if I am missing anything or following any wrong step.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi Team,

This is resolved. 

The issue was with the linux server memory. It is only 1 GiB for t2.micro instance, whereas my website requires 1.95 GiB to run.

The website was migrated successfully, all the files, database, url changes were fine; but the wp-admin did not open and server was getting disconnected as CPU utilization was crossing limits.

Happy, was able to spot this out.

Was able to spot it out as below:
Renamed all plugins directories and then tried opening wp-admin page which opened successfully with the new server domain name. (Thanks Kulikov and Kuldip: your suggestions followed and worked).

Then, activated plugins one by one; and as the number of plugins increased, noticed that server started responding slowly. Then checked the CPU utilization graph under monitoring in EC2 console which showed limits extended. Also checked using top.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that your new domain name differs from your old one. If it's so, you should execute the following SQL for the new database:

```
UPDATE [table_prefix]options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, '[from]', '[to]') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE [table_prefix]wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '[from]', '[to]');
UPDATE [table_prefix]postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, '[from]','[to]');
UPDATE [table_prefix]termmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, '[from]','[to]');
UPDATE [table_prefix]posts SET `guid` = replace(`guid`, '[from]','[to]');
```

`[table_prefix]` - is your $table_prefix (look for it in your wp-config.php)
`[from]` - is your old site URL (e.g. http://example-old.com)
`[to]` - is your new site URL (e.g. http://example-new.com)

Comment: Hi, I have already tried these steps as I mentioned, but doesn't help. Yes, domain names differ; and what I actually need is access the migrated site on new server, with the public DNS of the EC2 instance, but it shows my old site url.

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to replace your old path to new path in database.

Open your phpmyadmin -> select your appropriate database name 
Go to wp_options table there are two option_name 1) siteurl 2) home_url please change to new domain.

After that login into your new website admin panel go to permalinks and select plain after that select post_name url it will reflect old url to new url in your database.

Comment: Do I need to perform the second step in live database?

Comment: I have the credentials; but I do not want to disturb my live site yet.

Comment: but you told that your live site not working properly.!!

Comment: My live site is working properly; I want to access my new install on new server using new ip-address for testing purpose.